# Problema com a Estrutura Condicional Se e Senão

Tags: algoritmo, visualg, portugol

Gostaria de saber porque o programa não exibe o Aproveitamento do aluno :

```
   Escreva("Digite a primeira nota: ")
   Leia(nota1)
   Escreva("Digite a segunda nota: ")
   Leia(nota2)
   media <- (nota1 + nota2) / 2
   Escreval("Media : ",media)

   Se (media >= 10) e (media < 9) entao
      Escreval(" Aproveitamento : A")
   Senao
        Se (media >= 9) e (media < 8) entao
             Escreval("Aproveitamento : B")
        Senao
             Se (media >= 8) e (media < 7) entao
                Escreval("Aproveitamento : C")
             Senao
                  Se (media >= 7) e (media < 6) entao
                    Escreval("Aproveitamento : D")
                  Senao
                       Se (media >= 6) e (media < 5) entao
                           Escreval("Aproveitamento : E")
                       Senao
                            Se (media < 5) entao
                               Escreval("Aproveitamento : F")
                            FimSe
                       FimSe
                  FimSe
             FimSe
        FimSe
   FimSe

fimalgoritmo
```

Comment: Qual erro você está enfrentando?

Comment: O programa não exibe o Aproveitamento do aluno.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sua lógica esta invertida, verifique os sinais de maior " > " e menor " < ", do jeito que tá não satisfaz nenhuma condição.

Comment: Muito obrigado, não tinha observado esse problema e agora que eu invertir o código funciona normalmente!!